# Changing the position of the name in the function create('point') (jsxgraph)

Tags: javascript, jsxgraph

I am using `create('point')` to give some logic path a name.

In the following example I am drow a vertical path and one point at the top of the path and gave it the name 'A'.

```
SGH.LogicPath([3,-1],[3,-14],0.0);
SGH.b.create('point',[3,-1],{size:.2, withLabel:true, name:'A', color: 'none'});
```

The problem is that Name 'A' is shifted to right, I would like it excatly on top of the drawn point. Is there any way to change the position of the name?

Answer (score 1):

From version 0.94 (will be released on 4/2/2012) JSXGraph will have options for doing this.
Then, you can modify your example to

```
SGH.b.create('point',[3,-1],
    {size:.2, withLabel:true, name:'A', color: 'none', 
    label:{position:'top', offsets:[0,10]}});
```

With position ('lft', 'llft', 'ulft', 'top', 'bot', 'rt', 'lrt', 'urt') the direction can be controlled, with offsets:[x,y] the exact position (in px) can be adjusted.
The exact values for offsets depend on your font.

Comment: @ Alfred Wassermann I have download the new version and modified as u wrote but no change. Any Idea?

Comment: Sorry, did not saw your comment. This is a bug which is fixed in the next release. As a workaround you can set `JXG.Options.point.label = {};` before the call of `initBoard()`

Comment: @AlfredWassermann Can we make that label dragable ? I have a question If you can resolve that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17468204/how-can-i-make-point-label-dragable-in-jsxgraph

Answer (score 0):

You can use `label : { offset: [0,0] } // in pixels.` your code will like :

```
SGH.b.create('point',[3,-1],
    {size:.2, withLabel:true, name:'A', color: 'none', 
    label:{offset:[0,0]}});
```