# How can I make point label draggable in JSXGraph?

Tags: jsxgraph

I want to make my point label draggable , how can I achieve that in JSXGraph ? I got a link for re positioning polygon label http://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/wiki/index.php/Positioning_of_labels  but How can I change a point label ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
board.create('point',[1,1],
  {
    name: 'A',
    label: {
      fixed:false
    }
  });
```